# Online and Local site not looking the same on same screen and browser

Tags: css, rendering, jsx, next.js

So my problem is the following: my website doesn't look the same local and online. It is linked to the same git repository and same css file, however. I can open the page in local and online on same browser and same screen.

Everything seems linked correctly, since when I update the git repo from my local project, I see the changes on the online project. Except for some css property.

On local: the font-size is much bigger and more appropriate, and the flex/height of the container div are all Ok.

Online: font-size is way too small; div doesn't have proper height, and flex aren't respected.

Any idea what the problem is?

I'm using Digital Ocean for hosting the website and Buddyworks for linking my github  to Digital Ocean. I'm sure auto upgrade is enabled because when I add content, it is showed on the online version.
The project itself is in NextJs and CSS.

Any help is welcome. I'm using Chrome but tried also Firefox as well and the same issues are happening.

Screen of local rendering:
https://ibb.co/rGL7Y7j
Screen of online rendering:
https://ibb.co/8sPkjJS

PS : Sorry for my English, I'm not an English native speaker :)

Comment: You should post a repo or sandbox to illustrate what you are describing. are you using global css or css modules?

Comment: Its global css file created by npx-create-react-app. going to take screen and post picture if that can help in a few minutes

Comment: how can we help you with just captures?

Comment: in case  you are a french speaker, on ne peut pas t'aider juste avec des captures, il faut un minimum de code pour comprendre pourquoi le css ne s'applique pas bien en production et si tu n'as pas de contraintes, je te conseillerai de deployer ton application sur vercel

Comment: Thanx everyone for your anwser ; but since it's professional project i can't share  anything beside css file wich is 2800 line long .... i'll close the post and edit it if i find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's my bad, for some reason the second broswer window didn't open in same zoom level than first one ...

Answer (score 0):

If it happens to anyone again, I just had the same issue today except that the fonts were way bigger online and it was not a zoom issue.

I made my web app with ReactJs and I simply forgot to build it before deploy it (on Netlify).